# wordpress wpdb - get_results as json

Tags: wordpress

A json string is stored in a custom table field. When I try to retrieve it, some slashes get added:

```
[{"parameters":"{\"mytext1\":\"la ciudad..\",\"mytext2\":\"la playa\",\"mytext3\":\"la escuela\"}"},{"parameters":"{\"tipoOperacion\":\"suma\",\"decimales\":\"s\\u00ed\",\"numeros\":\"d0-100\"}"},{"parameters":"{\"direction\":\"EsteOeste\"}"},{"parameters":"{\"direction\":\"EsteOeste\"}"}]
```

Using stripslashes_deep or stripslashes actually remove slashes, but also create an invalid json string.

How can I process this text in order to get a working json string?

Answer (score 0):

You can just json_decode the string and you will get an array

```
print_r(json_decode('[{"parameters":"{\"mytext1\":\"la ciudad..\",\"mytext2\":\"la playa\",\"mytext3\":\"la escuela\"}"},{"parameters":"{\"tipoOperacion\":\"suma\",\"decimales\":\"s\\u00ed\",\"numeros\":\"d0-100\"}"},{"parameters":"{\"direction\":\"EsteOeste\"}"},{"parameters":"{\"direction\":\"EsteOeste\"}"}]'));
```

Comment: Thanks, it does parse, however what I missed is that I need to pass this data to js. Any idea on how to send it back to js without adding slashes again?

Comment: Once you are done manipulating your array you can json encode it and pass to js. Actually it depends how you pass it to js. If you are sending it via ajax than you can just print_r an array and then on the js side you need to JSON.parse data and you will get an object.

Comment: slashes are handled automatically

Comment: At js, I was just using var ljs = '<?php rJson(); ?>';  rJson in this case is just an echo of the json string. I didn't wanted to do any processing in  php other than retrieving that custom field, but got stuck in the slashes issue. If I do json encode, I still get the slashes.

Comment: try  $ar = json_decode('your string with slashes');  then var ljs = <?php echo json_encode($ar) ?>;

Comment: Tried without getting it to work, I thought it was a wordpress thing but most likely it's general on php. Will ask on php forum. Thanks again.